# Pycharm: trouble with importing ssl module

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

**Stack**:
windows 8.1
Anaconda2/python 3.7 env
Pycharm professional 2017.3

**Problem**:
Can't import ssl module (narrowed down the problem to loading _ssl.pyd):

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

**What i've tried:**

If I use my windows console to activate the conda enviroment and try to import ssl it works

sys.path output in pycharm:

> ['C:/Users/vlad/Documents/DjangoProjects/cryptodata/playing_around_aiohttp', 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev', 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev', 'C:\Users\vlad\.PyCharm2017.3\system\cythonExtensions', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\python37.zip', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\lib', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.3\helpers\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']

sys.path output in win console:

> ['', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\python37.zip', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\lib', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\lib\site-packages']

imp.find_module('_ssl') output in pycharm:

> (<_io.BufferedReader name='C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs\_ssl.pyd'>, 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs\_ssl.pyd', ('.pyd', 'rb', 3))

imp.find_module('_ssl') output in windows console:

> (<_io.BufferedReader name='C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs\_ssl.pyd'>, 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs\_ssl.pyd', ('.pyd', 'rb', 3))

In windows console I do "import _ssl" successfuly and then do

```
_ssl.__file__
```

the output of that is 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\373\DLLs\_ssl.pyd'

Am I missing something? What's going on here?

Comment: You should use Anaconda3 if you use Python 3.
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a new try

Comment: Try to update PyCharm, many Anaconda issues had been fixed recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by uninstalling Anaconda and using virtualenv instead. My decision of using virtualenv instead of Anaconda is subjective.

What I did:

1. Uninstall Anaconda
2. Install latest python
3. Install pip
4. Install virtualenv
5. Create virtualenv inside each working project. Enable the enviroment with "env/Scripts/activate"
6. Set pycharm project interpreter to the virtual environ executable. Pycharm should detect it by default

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue. However, `Anaconda has too much magic to understand how PyCharm interacts with it. Using virtualenv is cleaner but setting up takes a little more time.` is not objective. Anaconda works in a very similar way as pipenv. Anaconda3 currently comes with Python 3.7, and one can create a conda environmnent inside a Pycharm project in the exact same way one creates a pipenv environment.

Comment: I agree that it my choice for virtualenv was a bit subjective. I just prefer to have my virtual enviroments inside my project folder and virtualenv allows me to do so unlike Anaconda which installs everything in one central folder. Also, I find conda commands to run quite slow.